# Node.js REST API: Cannot find module './utility/utiliy'

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest, express

I've been following this tutorial: [REST API using Node.js and SQL SERVER](https://medium.com/@bbkashikar/create-rest-api-with-node-js-and-sql-server-as-database-550be4471fb6)

At some point in the tutorial (in the GET method section) you're supposed to create a dbContext.js file in which the code begins as follows:

```
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var connection = require('./connect');
var utility = require('./utility/utility');
(...)
```

Now, the problem is, the tutorial doesn't say anything about the ***./utility/utility***, so I don't know what I am supposed to write in it, or even *if* I am supposed to create it manually.

Naturally, as it doesn't exist, running the code results in

```
user@linuxmachine:~/project/Database$ node dbContext.js
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './utility/utility'
(...)
```

So, as a humble beginner, I ask: What am I supposed to do here?
Am I missing something?

Google hasn't helped, I can't contact the tutorial author and I haven't found anyone else talking about this.
I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: utility is just a file having few functions to return the db response . You can write your own code instead of using utility file.

Comment: you can download the code from the author's github .. https://github.com/BhaveshKashikar/NodeWithSql/tree/master/Database/utility

Answer (score 0):

In the GitHub repository [REST API with Node.js ans SQL Server](https://github.com/BhaveshKashikar/NodeWithSql) he provides the **./utility/utility.js** file. I don't understand why he didn't mention it in the tutorial, but I do know that I feel stupid right now.

Hope this helps someone in the future.